# this.test is not a function cordova ondevice ready

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova

Inside of my app.component.ts I have:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private fireBaseService: FirebaseService, ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.run();
    document.addEventListener('deviceready',  this.fireBaseService.onDeviceReady, false);

  }
```

In my firebase service I have (simplified in reallity I want to do more than console.log()):

```
export class FirebaseService {
  output = '';

  private audioObj = new Audio();

  constructor() {
    console.log('initialized firebaseservice');

  }

  test() {
    console.log('test');
  }


  onDeviceReady() {
    this.test();
  }
}
```

When I run my application I can see in the console:

> initialized firebaesservice
>
> this.test is not a function.

How can I call the test() method from within onDeviceReady() inside the firebaseservice?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess the scope of `this` is different. you can google javascript this context and get an explanation

try

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.run();
    document.addEventListener('deviceready',  this.fireBaseService.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

  }
```

or imo cleaner:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.run();
    document.addEventListener('deviceready',  () => {
        this.fireBaseService.onDeviceReady(); 
    }, false);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks it indeed works, I knew a bit about the this context but I was still expecting a function call within the same class to have the same this context.